# SQLServer decimal insert into bigint column loses precision but no error thrown

Tags: decimal, sql-server-2014, precision, sql-insert, bigint

The code below demonstrates inserting a decimal value with a precision into a bigint column using a standard insert statement. 
SqlServer truncates the precision but does not throw an error to notify the DBA.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableX]
(
    [ColumnA] [bigint] NULL
);

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

insert into [dbo].[TableX] (ColumnA)
select 999999999.99;

select * from [dbo].[TableX] 
-- output ==> 999999999 (precision missing) -- no error thrown?
```

**Question:**

I. Can you explain why the precision is lost and no error is thrown?

II. and can you suggest a way to force SQLServer to throw an error in this case?

**Note:**
SQL bulk insert will raise an error when attempting to convert a decimal to bigint when precision will be lost, so I am fairly certain there must be a way to achieve this with a standard insert statement as per the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your first question is that it is by design: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Which consequently means that for your second question you will need to add in some logic that checks for decimal values and handles them in the way you require.

---

On your final point about bulk inserting - I am not 100% on this so will gladly take advice - I believe this is because SQL Server has no idea what the data type is in your flat file, so everything is a string.  You can then state that it should be converted to a `date` or an `int` and SQL will attempt a conversion.

Conversions from strings to `decimal` and `int` data types are much more strict, which is why your `bulk insert` throws the error, as you can see in the below:

```
declare @t table([ColumnA] decimal(12,2) NULL);

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

insert into @t(ColumnA)
select '9999.99';

select * from @t
-- output ==> 9999.99 -- no error thrown

go

declare @t table([ColumnA] [bigint] NULL);

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

insert into @t(ColumnA)
select '9999.99';

select * from @t
-- output ==> error thrown
```

Comment: Good feedback. So instead of adding validation I went with wrapping all values within single quotes which results in errors with any loss of precision.